# connecting to onchange event of an objects innerHTML

Tags: dojo

I have a code which looks like this:-

```
<li><span id="readmon"></span></li>
```

I am changing the innerHTML of the above tag somehow and when it is changed I want to call a function, so I do a dojo.connect like this:-

```
dojo.connect(dojo.byId('readmon'),"onchange",netincome);
```

But I find that even though the innerHTML of the above changes, the function netincome is never called. Cant a change in innerHTML be found like this. If not , could someone please suggest a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to do that exactly as you would like to.  I don't think `onchange` can be applied to any element, only ones that the user can change.  I think the best you can do would be to make a function to change the `innerHTML` and call the `netincome` method from there:

```
function changeReadmon(newHTML)
{
    document.getElementById('readmon').innerHTML = newHTML;
    netincome();
}
```

Then call this method whenever you need to change the `innerHTML`.